# Exponential regression and focus on small values

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression

I have a set of data with 3 numeric variables: `X`, `Y` and `Z`.

I have access to data with 15 <= `X` + `Y` <= 40 *(training set)*.

The goal is to predict the value of `Z` when 40 < `X` + `Y` <= 60. *(test set)*.

From this graph I had the idea of modelling with this equation :

`Z = A * exp(-B*X) * exp(-C*Y)`

In other words,  `Z` has a initial value equals to `A` when `X` and `Y` are nil, and `X` and `Y` cause an exponential decay at different speed.

As we can see the effect of `X` is bigger than the effect of `Y` then B should be greater than C.

This model has the advantage to be linear after log transformation:
`Log(Y) = log(A) - B*X - C*Y`

I applied a OLS regression and the results are not good!

**Problems:**

1. Some value of C are nil so I added a very small value to `Z`. It's called `Z2`. `Z2 = Z +0.001`
2. The prediction are bad:

Since the errors are computed after log transformation, the OLS tends to focus on the prediction of small values and big values'prediction are bad.

**Potential solutions**

Here are the solutions I have in mind but I think there is a better way.

1. Find a better model than `Z = A * exp(-B*X) * exp(-C*Y)`
2. Use the solution from the OLS after log transformation as initial parameters of a non-linear regression.